# Capacitor iOS App not showing up in Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor

I need to test Geolocation in my Ionic Capacitor App. In previous projects the App would appear in the Settings with their permission, however this one particular app does not appear. I want to disable Location tracking once I have enabled it from the App. I do not see the App in the Settings of Simulator devices nor on my own device, iPhone XR and on my coworkers iPhone X.

In the info.plist I have the required Usage description keys `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

I am not familiar with xCode projects but I tried to look for any setting that might need to be enabled but I haven't found anything so far.

The other questions that I have looked at here on StackOverflow did not help. Restarting my phone does not help and force closing the Settings app does not help.

Comment: I think an app wont show up in settings until the permissions for that feature is allowed by the user first.

Comment: @johnborges I did have to accept Location permissions when I start my app, the problem is that I cannot disable it anymore. Only deleting the app and reinstalling will give me the prompt again.